# regex: how exclude a possible word that follows if it does

Tags: c#, regex

I'm reading a list by line and using regex in c# to capture the fields:

> fed line 1: Type: eBook Year: 1990 Title: This is ebook 1 ISBN:15465452 Pages: 100 Authors: Cendric, Paul
>
> fed line 2: Type: Movie Year: 2016 Title: This is movie 1 Authors: Pepe Giron ; Yamasaki Suzuki Length: 4500 Media Type: DVD

```
string pattern = @"(?:(Type: )(?<type>\w+)) *(?:(Year: )(?<year>\d{4})) *(?:(Title: )(?<title>[^ISBN]*))(?:(ISBN:) *(?<ISBN>\d*))* *(?:(Pages: )(?<pages>\d*))* *(?:(Authors: )(?<author1>[\w ,]*)) *;* *(?<author2>[\w ,]*) *(?:(Length: )(?<length>\d*))* *(?:Media Type: )*(?<discType>[\w ,]*)";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern);
```

If the line fed has "Length: " I want to stop capturing the surname of the Author excluding the word Length.

If I use `(?:(Length: )(?<length>\d*))*` Length is added to the surname of the second author for `match.Groups["author2"].Value`. If I use `(?:(Length: )(?<length>\d*))+` I get no matches for the first line.

Can you please give me guidance.
Thank you, Sergio

Comment: *[^ISBN]* is wrong. It will stop to any one of the letters I, S, B, N, not at the word ISBN

Comment: And in general your solution seems to be quite brittle, unless you are very sure of the format of the line. It would be probably better to search for the tags (Type:, Year:, ...) "manually" (with `string.IndexOf`) instead of fighting against the vagaries of regexes

Comment: I agree with @xanatos - these look like name/value pairs. I would write code to parse them into that.

Comment: What are the rules? What makes `Media Type` different from `Suzuki Length`

Comment: @Eser `keyword:` (keyword colon) is a reserved word (e.g. Media Type:)... That is brittle in itself. Whoever wrote the format should be kicked down the hill.

Answer (score 1):

Using full regexes for something as fuzzy as the format you have is always a way for hurting themselves. As written by @Kevin, you should look for the keys and extract the values.

My proposal is looking for those keys and splitting the string before and after them. There is a nifty, randomly working (they even changed its working between .NET 1.1 and .NET 2.0), nearly unknown feature of Regex that is called `Regex.Split()`. We could try to use it :-)

```
string pattern = @"(?<=^| )(Type: |Year: |Title: |ISBN:|Pages: |Authors: |Length: |Media Type: )";
var rx = new Regex(pattern);
string[] parts = rx.Split(line);
```

Now `parts` is an array where if in an element there is a key, in the next element there is the value... The `Regex.Split` can add an empty element at the beginning of the array.

```
string type = null, title = null, mediaType = null;
int? year, length;
string[] authors = new string[0];


// The parts[0] == string.Empty ? 1 : 0 is caused by the "strangeness" of Regex.Split
// that can add an empty element at the beginning of the string
for (int i = parts[0] == string.Empty ? 1 : 0; i < parts.Length; i += 2)
{
    string key = parts[i].TrimEnd();
    string value = parts[i + 1].Trim();
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}|{1}]", key, value);

    switch (key)
    {
        case "Type:":
            type = value;
            break;
        case "Year:":
            {
                int temp;
                if (int.TryParse(value, out temp))
                {
                    year = temp;
                }
            }
            break;
        case "Title:":
            title = value;
            break;
        case "Authors:":
            {
                authors = value.Split(" ; ");
            }
            break;
        case "Length:":
            {
                int temp;
                if (int.TryParse(value, out temp))
                {
                    length = temp;
                }
            }
            break;
        case "Media Type:":
            mediaType = value;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After all, @xanathos is right. An overcomplicated regex that is hard to maintain and error prone may not serve you well in the long run.

But to answer your question, your regex can be fixed with a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat)*, e.g. do not allow `Length:` in the author's pattern:

```
(?:(?:(?!Length: )[\w ,])*)
```

<sub>* The linked description uses a `.` in the greedy token but it's useful to limit the range of allowed characters more here.</sub>

Arguably, this should be added to the `author1` and `author2` part.

The final pattern then looks like this:

`(?:(Type: )(?<type>\w+)) *(?:(Year: )(?<year>\d{4})) *(?:(Title: )(?<title>[^ISBN]*))(?:(ISBN:) *(?<ISBN>\d*))* *(?:(Pages: )(?<pages>\d*))* *(?:(Authors: )(?<author1>(?:(?:(?!Length: )[\w ,])*) *)) *;* *(?<author2>(?:(?:(?!Length: )[\w ,])*) *)(?:(Length: )(?<length>\d*))* *(?:Media Type: )*(?<discType>[\w ,]*)`

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/hWjC9K/1)